# Combination of escapeshellcmd and escapeshellarg

Tags: php

I found a very strange bug in my application today and I am not properly sure, how to fix it.

A form allows a user to do something. For this it needs to invoke a external command via system. So I decided to use `escapeshellcmd` for this purpose.

```
<?php
$foo = "abc&d";
$bar = "abc d";

$command = sprintf("/bin/command '%s' '%s'", $foo, $bar);
var_dump(escapeshellcmd($command)); //"/bin/command 'abc\&d' 'abc d'"
?>
```

which is not what I wanted (note the wrong `\&` which gives an extra, unwanted char '\').
So I came up with three different solutions and I don't know which one I should prefer, because only one gives me correct solution.

```
<?php
$foo = "abc&d";
$bar = "abc d";

$command1 = sprintf("/bin/command %s %s", $foo, $bar);
var_dump(escapeshellcmd($command1)); //"/bin/command abc\&d abc d" <- now we have three arguments

$command2 = sprintf("/bin/command %s %s", escapeshellarg($foo), escapeshellarg($bar));
var_dump($command2); //"/bin/command 'abc&d' 'abc d'" <- correct-ish?

$command3 = sprintf("/bin/command %s %s", escapeshellarg($foo), escapeshellarg($bar));
var_dump(escapeshellcmd($command3)); //"/bin/command 'abc\&d' 'abc d'" <- extra '\'
?>
```

Which of these solutions is prefered other the other? Why? Is there another (proper) solution for this dilemma?

Comment: you should prefer the escaping of each argument separately

Comment: @IVOGELOV Give ma reason why, preferable something to read and make it an answer ;)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/40d02da5e07f151adeaeeaa11af9ab36 
            ;             https://baesystemsai.blogspot.com/2013/11/security-issues-with-using-phps.html

Comment: Thanks :) That is a nice one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$command2 = sprintf("/bin/command %s %s", escapeshellarg($foo), escapeshellarg($bar));
var_dump($command2); //"/bin/command 'abc&d' 'abc d'" <- correct-ish?
```

The only reason you would ever want to use `escapeshellcmd` is if you wanted to allow spaces within variables to separate arguments. If you just want to pass the arguments with escaping, use `escapeshellarg`.